# Applying Focus to a Textfield in LWUIT

Tags: lwuit

I created a customised keyboard in `LWUIT` as follows. I put a textfield and put buttons from "A-Z" and added actionlistener to each button so that it displays in the text field. Now my problem is there is no focus available. If I need to edit a letter in the middle of a word there is no way except to delete all the letters till then and correct it. So my question is how to implement a focuspointer in text field so that i can change any letter at any place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create FocusListener and implement what you want, and then use function add lisitner to text field :

```
textFiledInstance.addFocusListener(Focus Listner instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a custom VirtualKeyboard, I recommend you to use the resource editor.

You must take a look on this  [LWUIT VKB](http://lwuit.blogspot.com.es/2010/06/pimp-virtualkeyboard-by-chen-fishbein.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about moving the cursor in the virtual keyboard in LWUIT?

All you need to do is touch the field within the VKB, not the text field being edited (which will close the VKB). This will move the cursor.